# Out of 6 column headers with dates, how do I return the next date in line and all of its rows?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I'm trying to figure out a formula to return the next coming Sunday from the image provided and all the rows of true / false. I've tried index(match but it only returns 6 rows and doesn't return the date header text. I was able to do this with an importrange but I had to hard code the date cell reference. I instead want to search for the next date value in a range and auto pop the data. Any help would be amazing, thank you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1W4kg.jpg)

Comment: Could you share your index-match try?

Comment: =ArrayFormula(Transpose(index(AC3:AH22,MATCH(Z2, AC3:AH3,0))))